# GMSAutocompleteViewController not returning result

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am using GMSAutocompleteViewController, I requested for places but it return following errors.

```
load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://dl.google.com/geosdk/ios-latest, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://dl.google.com/geosdk/ios-latest, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <2F577B35-9DE3-4EF9-B5FC-C1E6220F8637>.<1>"
```

Why i am getting this kind of error? Is there any configuration problem or anything else?

Comment: problem with  network please try open network

Comment: Network is good.

Comment: proxy blocking issue try open network like your mobile data and so on

Comment: Its already on Mobile Data